# How to generate random character from more than one source in Python?

Tags: python, random, constants

I'm trying to generate some random characters but I want to include string.letters, string.digits, and string.punctuation. I can do any one of them, but how to include all three (or additional) sources/constants?

```
import random
import string

for i in range(0,4):
    print(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
```

This code will choose a letter - would like to include digits and punctuation symbols also...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a source with all the things you want:

```
import random
import string

source = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits

for i in range(0,4):
    print(random.choice(source))
```

Prints:

```
E
)
2
h
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a list with all of the characters that you want, and sample from that.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

for i in range(0,4):
    print(random.choice(alphabet))
```

If your lists are really big and you don't want to create a giant alphabet, you can do weighted random sampling from the alphabets (weighted by size), and then uniform random from each alphabet.